# Pandas date_range inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, pandas

When using the pandas (v. 13.1) date_range function I get inconsistent behavior about whether or not the 'end' is inside in the returned range:

```
In [1]: pd.date_range(start='2014-06-09 15:36:55', 
                      end='2014-06-09 15:37:46', 
                      freq='20s')
Out[1]: [2014-06-09 15:36:55, ..., 2014-06-09 15:37:55]
```

And

```
In [2]: pd.date_range(start='2014-06-09 15:36:55', 
                      end='2014-06-09 15:37:46', 
                      freq='10s')
Out[2]: [2014-06-09 15:36:55, ..., 2014-06-09 15:37:45]
```

Note that in the first case the last time is later that the specified 'end', while in the second case the last time is smaller. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I would guess that it is rounding to the nearest frequency boundary.  46 is closer to 55 than to 35 (20 seconds before), but closer to 45 to 55.  However, I agree that is confusing behavior.  It might be worth asking on the pandas mailing list and/or raising a bug in the tracker.

Comment: My guess is it's while current < end yield the next one (so it generates one too many), but I can't quite see where this would come from. Definitely post and issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this issue has already been fix in some release. Now the `date_range` behaviour is consistent, always including the `start` and *the end of the `DatetimeIndex`* always <= `end`. And the output format became pretty too.

Following code is using pandas 0.17.0:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.date_range(start='2014-06-09 15:36:55', 
   ...:                       end='2014-06-09 15:37:46', 
   ...:                       freq='20s')
Out[2]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2014-06-09 15:36:55', '2014-06-09 15:37:15',
               '2014-06-09 15:37:35'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='20S')

In [3]: pd.date_range(start='2014-06-09 15:36:55', 
                      end='2014-06-09 15:37:46', 
                      freq='10s')
Out[3]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2014-06-09 15:36:55', '2014-06-09 15:37:05',
               '2014-06-09 15:37:15', '2014-06-09 15:37:25',
               '2014-06-09 15:37:35', '2014-06-09 15:37:45'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='10S')

In [4]: pd.date_range(start='2014-06-09 15:36:55', 
                      end='2014-06-09 15:37:46', 
                      freq='15s')
Out[4]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2014-06-09 15:36:55', '2014-06-09 15:37:10',
               '2014-06-09 15:37:25', '2014-06-09 15:37:40'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='15S')

In [5]: pd.date_range(start='2014-06-09 15:36:55', 
                      end='2014-06-09 15:37:46', 
                      freq='1s')
Out[5]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2014-06-09 15:36:55', '2014-06-09 15:36:56',
                   ......                    ......
               '2014-06-09 15:37:45', '2014-06-09 15:37:46'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='S')
```

Note that the end of the `DatetimeIndex` never exceeds `end` date of `date_range`.